# Creating new column from existing columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame

```
ID   P_1   P_2
1    NaN   NaN
2    124   342
3    NaN   234
4    123   NaN
5    2345  500
```

I want to make a new column titled P_3 such that:

```
ID   P_1   P_2  P_3
1    NaN   NaN   NaN
2    124   342   342
3    NaN   234   234
4    123   NaN   123
5    2345  500  500
```

My conditions are:

```
if P_1 = Nan , then P_3 == P_2
if P_1 != Nan and P_2 != Nan, then  P_3 == P_2
if P_2 = Nan , then P_3 == P_1
```

I have applied the following codes:

```
conditions = [
    (df['P_1'] == float('NaN')),
    (df['P_1'] != float('NaN')) & (df['P_2'] != float('NaN')),
    (df['P_1'] != float('NaN')) & (df['P_2'] == float('NaN'))
    ]

values = [df['P_2'], df['P_2'], df['P_1']]

df['P_3'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Length of values does not match length of index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In summary, your unique condition is:

```
P_3 = P_2 if P_2 != NaN else P_1
```

`combine_first`: update null elements with value in the same location in other (ref: Pandas doc.)

```
>>> df["P_2"].combine_first(df["P_1"])
ID
1      NaN
2    342.0
3    234.0
4    123.0
5    500.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
In [93]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[93]: 
       p1     p2
0     NaN    NaN
1   124.0  342.0
2     NaN  234.0
3   123.0    NaN
4  2345.0  500.0

In [94]: df['p3'] = df.p2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [95]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[95]: 
       p1     p2     p3
0     NaN    NaN    NaN
1   124.0  342.0  342.0
2     NaN  234.0  234.0
3   123.0    NaN    NaN
4  2345.0  500.0  500.0

In [96]: df.loc[df.p3.isna(), 'p3'] = df[df.p3.isna()]['p1']                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [97]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[97]: 
       p1     p2     p3
0     NaN    NaN    NaN
1   124.0  342.0  342.0
2     NaN  234.0  234.0
3   123.0    NaN  123.0
4  2345.0  500.0  500.0
```

Comment: A more simpler version of your answer would be: `df["P_3"] = df["P_2"].fillna(df["P_1"])`